# Matching different data sets to create a new list in R

Tags: r

I have two data sets. One that looks like this:

```
    Male      Female     Territory    
 1  1         11          TEE          
 2  2         12          JEB          
 3  3         13          GAT  
 4  4         14          SHY
 5  5         15          BOB  
 6  6         16          LEE
 7  7         17          BOO
 8  8         18          DON
 9  9         19          RAZ
10  10        20          ZAP
```

This data set tells us the ID numbers of the male and females (these are the observed mating pairs- for example, male 1 and female 11 were observed to have mated and the territory they occupy is called TEE), and the territory name that they live in.

The other data set looks like this:

```
   $GAT
   [1] "TEE" "SHY" "BOB"

   $JEB
   [1] "LEE" "GAT" "BOO"

   $TEE
   [1] "DON" "RAZ" "ZAP"
```

This second data set lists the surrounding territories for each territory. For example, territories TEE, SHY, and BOB surround the territory GAT.

Both of these data sets are in character form.

What I am trying to do is make a list of potential mates for every female individual based on the territories that surround the territory they reside in and the males that live in those surrounding territories. So my end goal is to get something that looks like this:

```
    $11
    [1] "8" "9" "10"

    $12
    [1] "6" "3" "7"

    $13
    [1] "1" "4" "5"

    etc...
```

So I have to try and match the territory that each female resides in to the surrounding territory list to get the list of surrounding territories for each female. Then I have to find all the males that reside in those surrounding territories (as well as the males that reside in the territory that the female resides in itself).

I'm honestly not even sure how to start this. Even something that can help me start this will be very appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Not clear about the logic of obtaining the expected output

Comment: Sorry about that. Are you asking what is the purpose of all this?

Comment: I am confused about how you got values 12, 32, 65 etc on the expected

Comment: Oh sorry! I should have explained that. I just put in random numbers and territory names because those two data sets I have are actually much longer than what I am showing. So for example, if I look at female 5, she resides in territory JEB and JEB is surrounded by LEE, GAT, BOO. In my desired list it is saying that male 98, male 3, and male 51 reside in one of those surrounding territories. Male 98 and 51 are not seen in my first data set but if the data set were to continue on they would be. Does that make sense? I'm going to edit the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I altered your example a bit to include a territory duplicate.

```
df <- data.frame(Male=1:4, Female=5:8, Territory=c("TEE","TEE","JEB","GAT"), Year=2013, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
#  Male Female Territory Year
#1    1      5       TEE 2013
#2    2      6       TEE 2013
#3    3      7       JEB 2013
#4    4      8       GAT 2013

neighbour <- list()
neighbour[['GAT']] <- c("TEE","SHY","BOB")
neighbour[['JEB']] <- c("LEE", "GAT", "BOO")
neighbour[['TEE']] <- c("DON", "RAZ", "ZAP")
#$GAT
#[1] "TEE" "SHY" "BOB"
#$JEB
#[1] "LEE" "GAT" "BOO"
#$TEE
#[1] "DON" "RAZ" "ZAP"
```

Here is a possible solution using `lapply` and `%in%`.

```
#iterate over all females
result <- lapply(setNames(nm=df$Female), function(x) {
    #territory of the current female
    FemTer <- df[df$Female == x, "Territory"]
    #males living in the neighbourhood
    df[df$Territory %in% c(FemTer, neighbour[[FemTer]]), "Male"]
})
result
#$`5`
#[1] 1 2
#
#$`6`
#[1] 1 2
#
#$`7`
#[1] 3 4
#
#$`8`
#[1] 1 2 4
```

I just assumed, that you would include the territory a female resides in as well as its surroundings. If you only want the surroundings, just delete the `FemTer,` from `df[df$Territory %in% c(FemTer, neighbour[[FemTer]]), "Male"]`.

Comment: For some reason when I do this it gives me this: "Error in neighbour[[FemTer]] : subscript out of bounds" so I tried doing it like this: neighbour[FemTer] but it only gives me the males in the same territory as the female, not the males in the surrounding territories

Comment: I'm trying to convert the list of neighbours into a data frame but it says this: "Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 3, 7, 4, 2, 8, 5, 6, 1, 12, 11"

Comment: I should also mention that my list of neighbours was generated using GIS and a shape file and the function gTouches. I'm not sure if that might affect how this code will work

Comment: Also, as I'm typing in neighbour[[FemTer]], this pops up: "(TypeError) : null is not an object (evaluating 'a.length')". Is this happening because in my neighbour list I have uneven lengths? How do I fix that?

Comment: @JenniferDiamond Sorry, that I didn't came around to answer your questions earlier.
One problem could be, that the names of the territories indexing the `neighbour`-list don't contain all possible territory names present in your first data set. If that is the case, simply add them. You may find that out using something like `nn <- names(neighbour)` and `ut <-
 unique(df$Territory)`. Print all missing territories with `nn[!(nn %in% ut)]` and add them to your list (with no neighbours?).

Answer (score 0):

Consider this base R data wrangling with `merge`, `reshape`, `by`:

**Data**

```
txt = '    Male      Female     Territory    
 1  1         11          TEE          
 2  2         12          JEB          
 3  3         13          GAT  
 4  4         14          SHY
 5  5         15          BOB  
 6  6         16          LEE
 7  7         17          BOO
 8  8         18          DON
 9  9         19          RAZ
10  10        20          ZAP'

df <- read.table(text=txt, header=TRUE)

territories <- list(GAT=c("TEE","SHY","BOB"), 
                    JEB=c("LEE","GAT","BOO"),
                    TEE=c("DON","RAZ","ZAP"))
```

**Process**

```
# CASE LIST TO DF
df_territories <- data.frame(territories, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# MELT DF TO LONG FORMAT
df_territories <- reshape(df_territories, varying = list(1:3), 
                          v.names="nearest", timevar="Territory", 
                          times=names(df_territories)[1:ncol(df_territories)],
                          direction="long")
# NESTED MERGE
mdf <- merge(merge(df, df_territories, by="Territory", all.x=TRUE),
             df, by.x="nearest", by.y="Territory")
# BY GROUP SLICE
matelist <- by(mdf, mdf$Female.x, FUN=function(grp){
  as.character(sort(grp$Male.y))
})

# LIST CLEANUP
attributes(matelist) <- NULL
names(matelist) <- unique(sort(mdf$Female.x))

matelist
# $`11`
# [1] "8"  "9"  "10"

# $`12`
# [1] "3" "6" "7"

# $`13`
# [1] "1" "4" "5"
```